# Round amount up to 2 decimal places in druid

Tags: sql, decimal, apache-superset, druid

I have a column Amount with data type as string.
I want to round these to 2 decimal places in Apache Druid.

For example:

- `0.0` should be `0.00`
- `3.0` should be `3.00`
- `5.6666` should be `5.67`

Comment: https://github.com/apache/druid/blob/0.15.0-incubating/core/src/main/java/org/apache/druid/math/expr/Function.java

Comment: https://www.druidforum.org/t/druid-round-function/4832/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until now you can't do that kind of rounding in Druid. I used this query without success:

```
--  0.0 should be 0.00 
--  3.0 should be 3.00 
--  5.6666 should be 5.67 
SELECT ROUND(0.01, 2) as test_value_1, --OUTPUT: 0.01
       ROUND(3.1231, 2) as test_value_2, --OUTPUT: 3.12
       ROUND(5.6666, 2) as test_value_3, --OUTPUT: 5.67
       ROUND(5.00, 2) as test_value_4, --OUTPUT: 5
       CAST(0 as DECIMAL) as value_5 --OUTPUT: 0
```

[image]

I have reviewed these documents [Expression](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/misc/math-expr.html) and in it we can read that:

> round(x, y) returns the value of the x rounded to the y decimal
> places. While x can be an integer or floating-point number, y must be
> an integer. The type of the return value is specified by that of x. y
> defaults to 0 if omitted. When y is negative, x is rounded on the left
> side of the y decimal points. If x is NaN, x returns 0. If x is
> infinity, x will be converted to the nearest finite double.

So, I think you will be able to round but not add the zeros.

If you want to force decimals even, you can use STRING_FORMAT:

```
SELECT STRING_FORMAT('%.2f', 0.0) as test_value_1, --OUTPUT: 0.00
       STRING_FORMAT('%.2f', 3.0) as test_value_2, --OUTPUT: 3.00
       STRING_FORMAT('%.2f', 5.6666) as test_value_3, --OUTPUT: 5.66
       STRING_FORMAT('%.2f', 1.0 * 0) as value_4 --OUTPUT: 0.00
```